# Is casting the same as converting in swift?

Tags: swift, casting, type-conversion

When stumbling across casting using "as! or as?", I also noticed that types could also be converted using the desired type inside of parenthesis such as:

```
let x : Int = 42
var myString = String(x)
```

This made me curious to ask if converting and casting are the same?  However when I tried to do converting in a another example using a reference type, I don't think the compiler allows this or at least it gave me an error, such as:

```
let sutCast = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController") as! ItemListViewController
let sutConvert = ItemListViewController(storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController"))
```

Is it safe to say or assume that in Swift, conversions are not allowed for reference types and casting is different from conversion because it depends if an object is a reference type or a value type?

Comment: What's the error the compiler gave you?

Comment: The error shows for variable "sutConvert" is Xcode's attempt to fix it and doesn't compile.  The error given in Xcode's attempt to fix is "Missing argument label 'coder:' in call" @AdamPro13

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html):

> Type casting is a way to check the type of an instance, or to treat that instance as a different superclass or subclass from somewhere else in its own class hierarchy.

It is a way to convert one type to another but it can also be used for more, such as to check the type etc.

Refer to the documentation for more info.